# Spinner Array needs to link it's items to existing layouts?

Tags: android, android-spinner

So the spinner I have currently picks from a programmatic array which fetches names and images based on what's in the array.
What I need is to only pick from items in the array if they exist based on the layouts I have.
eg. I have multiple accounts in my main activity list. I only want to be able to pick an account in my spinner based on the accounts I have available (user only has 2 of 3 accounts from the array, thus only display 2 items in the spinner not all 3)

Here's my current spinner code as well as the array:

**SpinnerActivity:**

```js
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<AccountItem> mAccountList;
    private AccountAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transactions);

        //the account_spinner is being pulled from the fragment_transactions xml
        initList();

        Spinner spinnerAccount = findViewById(R.id.account_spinner);

        mAdapter = new AccountAdapter(this, mAccountList);
        spinnerAccount.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        spinnerAccount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AccountItem clickedItem = (AccountItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String clickedAccountName = clickedItem.getAccountName();
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, clickedAccountName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

/**
*This is the array, I need this to link each item to their respective accounts
*that are available
**/
    private void initList() {
        mAccountList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAccountList.add(new AccountItem("Account1", R.drawable.account1_icon));
        mAccountList.add(new AccountItem("Account2", R.drawable.account2_icon));
        mAccountList.add(new AccountItem("Account3", R.drawable.account3_icon));
    }


}
```

I just need an idea of where to start. As it stands I don't see a way to give my array items individual IDs so I'm not sure if I need to change my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change the array. If you need to fetch the account list asynchronously, you can call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the async completion callback to tell the `Adapter` that its backing array has changed.